# Android: Activate loudspeaker during a call

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am trying to activate the loudspeaker during a call, is this possible?

```
    @Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    String number = args.getString(0);

    if( number.startsWith("tel:") == false){
        number = String.format("tel:%s", number);
    }

    try {
```

and here is the AudioManager

```
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);

        Intent intent = new Intent(isTelephonyEnabled() ? Intent.ACTION_CALL : Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
        cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        callbackContext.success();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        callbackContext.error("CouldNotCallPhoneNumber");
    }

    return true;
}
```

call works perfectly, but this does not activate speaker..

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this permission to your Manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Yes that's fine [code]     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />[/code]